# jquery select Table, but only after Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

On most my pages I have a specific div that holds the title for that page:

```
<div id="pagetitle">Some Title</div>
```

And usually immediately after is a table. 
I want to select all tables, but only tables after the #pagetitle div.

I intend to add some css to just those tables. Currently I am having to create a class and add that class to all the tables. But I have tons of pages.

Current code:

```
$('table.valigntop tr td').css('vertical-align','middle');
```

I need a little help with creating a cool jquery select statement that selects all tables that exist after the #pagetitle element.  Whether it's the best way for my sites is still to be determined.

Comment: Since the `~` sibling operator has been suggested in more than one answer but isn't working for you, the problem may actually be with the way you're selecting the `td` tag itself.  Perhaps you can post an example of one of the tables you're trying to style, so we can provide better assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use `nextAll()` Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Af6/

HTML:

```
<table><tr><td>table one</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table two</td></tr></table>
<div id='pagetitle'></div>
<table><tr><td>table three</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table four</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table five</td></tr></table>
```

CSS:

```
div, table{
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#pagetitle').nextAll('table').css("background", "yellow");
```

**EDIT** JS: Add the `td` selector http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Af6/1/

```
$('#pagetitle').nextAll('table').find('td').css("background", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the tables like this:

```
$("#pagetitle ~ table")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient fix would be to actually put those tables inside a container, and then you can just modify the tables inside that container.

A simple div with no css at all (except reset styles) would do.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "immediately after" it sounds like you mean "the `table` is at the same DOM level as the `div` -- in other words, it's a sibling of the `div`."  Is that right?

If so, you can use the jQuery [Next Siblings Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/). Something like this:

<strike>`$('#pagetitle ~ table.valigntop tr td').css('vertical-align','middle');`</strike>

Or see the examples at http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/, which should also get you what you want.

#### Edit

The more I look at the first version I posted, I realize that it is really looking for the `td` which is a sibling of `#pagetitle`, **not** the `table` which is a sibling of `#pagetitle`.

That means the correct way to accomplish this is to first select the tables using the sibling operator, *then* find those tables' children, more like this (http://jsfiddle.net/T3nuQ/6/):

```
$("#pagetitle ~ table").find('tr td').css('vertical-align','middle');
```

Comment: I want to negate the need to use ".valigntop".  I tried the ~ and so far it's not performing. Still testing other means though.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a snippet of code that includes the div *and* the table you are trying to style.  It may be an issue other than the `~` sibling operator.

Comment: Revised code and added a jsFiddle link, building on the jsFiddle from another answer.